# Delphi: How to install/enable Data Access Controls (Xmlxform)?

Tags: delphi, vcl, data-controls

in the my delphi xe5 haven't the palette Data Access Controls, I need the components Xmlxform.TXMLTransform, Xmlxform.TXMLTransformClient,...etc.

I'm tried install a package with the unit corresponding 'Xmlxform.pas' and after build but don't worked.

I called the Xmlxform to uses in my project but the functions don't work too.

I think that vcl components already installed , looks the link:

http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/Data_Access_Controls

Comment: What edition (SKU) of Delphi do you have (Professional, Enterprise, Architect)? Do you have RAD Studio or just Delphi? Your text says XE5, but the link says XE4, so what specific version and edition of Delphi are you using? (And we don't do "Thanks in advance" here; you can show your appreciation afterward by upvoting useful answers or accepting those that solve your problem directly.)

Comment: The RAD XE5 version, what about "thanks in advance", usually in my country we use this as a form of education. Thank disposal of a stranger to assist you as you.

Comment: I udnerstand it's a normal courtesy in your country, but it's not appropriate here. The proper way to show appreciation here is by voting; see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). Questions here should contain the relevant information from a technical standpoint; we're a question and answer site, not a discussion group or forum. :-) You also only answered half of my questions. Now that we've decided it's XE5, **what edition** (Professional, Standard, Architect, Enterprise) do you have? Features available differ between them.

Comment: Ok, I udnerstand too. Architect version.

Comment: Use "Components/Install Packages" from the main menu. In that dialog, look for "Embarcadero XML Components" in the list. Is the checkbox for that package checked? Do you have an open project (File->New->VCL Forms Application)? Is your Form Designer open to either a form or datamodule? (The palette won't show the components when the Code Editor is in use.)

Comment: In my version doesn't have "Embarcadero XML Components" in the list have. But in directory ...\bin have a file "xmlrtl190.bpl" Is this the component pack?

Comment: No. The package you're looking for is dclxml190.bpl. If it's not in the list, you didn't install it. Rerun the installation, choose "Repair", and look for anything that says "XML" and make sure it's checked.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57189/discussion-between-artur-indio-and-ken-white).

Comment: After discussion in chat, I've recommended that the poster open a free support case with [Embarcadero](http://support.embarcadero.com), because apparently the package isn't installed and isn't available to be installed. With no more information available, I'm voting to close this question as "unable to reproduce".

Comment: I will contact embarcadero, I agree.

Comment: I have one final question (based on a careful re-reading of your original question). It's a long shot, since you've said you don't have the .bpl file, but are you looking for the right component page? You mentioned "the palette Data Access Controls", but in XE5/6 the `TXMLTransform` component is on the "XML" palette page. Try using Ctrl+Alt+P to focus the component palette, and then typing "XMLT" - what happens?

Comment: Nothing, appears just 'TXMLdocument' on 'Internet' components.

Comment: Ok. They're definitely not installed. :-) Since this is an installation-related issue, you can open a free support case through the link I gave you above. I've mentioned everything that I can think of (other than a full uninstall/reinstall of Delphi) with no luck. :-(